# How to 'ScrollTo' specific Element of ScrollableColumn - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I want to scroll to a specific item inside a ScrollableColumn but how do I get the needed initial scrollValue without guessing it?

I want the scroll to start after the end of the composable TopAppBar

```kotlin
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
fun Content(data: DataObj, onEditAction: () -> Unit) {
    val items = listOf("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "")
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState(140f)

    Surface(contentColor = Color.DarkGray) {
        ScrollableColumn(scrollState = scrollState, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            TopAppBar(
                title = { Text("Edit Entry") },
                backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                actions = {
                    IconButton(onClick = onEditAction) {
                        Icon(asset = Icons.Filled.Edit)
                    }
                }
            )

            LazyColumnFor(items) { item ->
                Surface(Modifier.preferredHeight(50.dp).fillMaxWidth()) {
                    Text(item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Separate problem, but this code isn't going to do what you want it to.  You shouldn't have a `LazyColumnFor` inside a `ScrollableColumn`, as that will make it compose and lay out every single item immediately.

Comment: @RyanM How could I achieve the app bar appearing if I start a drag from the top to the bottom of the device and its initial state is hidden ?

Comment: Are you trying to achieve the effects of the Gmail Android app, where the toolbar gets animated based on an up/down scroll gesture?